# Distinct within case statement Mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

Is it possible to have distinct within a case in mssql. Something like this.

```
  select 
  sum(case when distinct(Ocid) and Code = 200 then 1 
  else 0 end) as something
  from mytable
```

If i don't want to modify the from clause is that possible in someother way?

Comment: you mean when count(distinct ocid) = 1?

Comment: Can you describe in plain English what you want? I can't understand what your intention is from your code

Comment: Are you returning other columns or just the single column [something]?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you want to do won't work.

This will check whether there's only one `Ocid` in the entire table.

```
select 
  sum(case when Code = 200 then 1 
      else 0 end) as something
from mytable
having count(distinct Ocid) = 1
```

This will count distinct `Ocid`'s that has a `Code` of 200:

```
select sum(something)
from
(
  select 
    count(*) as count,
    (case when max(Code) = 200 then 1 
     else 0 end) as something
  from mytable
  group by ocid
) a
where count = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10809/1).

**EDIT:** I'm not really sure what you want to do.

Comment: Well that should work but the question is, if its possible to solve without using a group by, and solve it in the select statement

Comment: @Love2Learn Reasons like what?

Comment: The Count(Distinct Ocid) is going to get a total unique count for all the Ocid in the table since it's not grouped on anything so unless there is only one Ocid it will always return 0. And as you mention if you aggregate it in the select you'll get a bunch of rows with a 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best so far, but it's not what you're asking for. You could do it easy with a CTE or subquery or whatever, but I'm not sure you can do it like you're asking.

```
Select  Sum(bah)
From   (Select  1 As bah
        From    mytable mt2
        Where   mt2.Code = 200
        Group   By mt2.Ocid
        Having  Count(mt2.Ocid) = 1) n
```

My answer for you is, "No", it is not possible to do what you're trying to do without making additional modifications. You will always dead end to this error:

```
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```